# getting random IllegalArgumentException on ContentResolver.delete() calls

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, illegalargumentexception

On my android app we have a `ContentProvider` with a few tables and every content resolver call is done against the same list of URIs (one for each table) and all of them are working fine on testing enviroment. I can't reproduce the bug but from GooglePlay we keep getting every once in a while this crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.myapp.urimanager.data/location
at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:818)
at com.myapp.geo.GeocodeProvider$MyHandler.handleMessage(GeocodeProvider.java:225)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

the specific line for this crash is just a simple `DELETE` request to the DB:

```
long when = System.currentTimeMillis() - (3 * MONTH);
String where = DbLocation.COL_TS + "<" + Long.toString(when);
int rowsDeleted = context.getContentResolver().delete(myUri, where, null);
```

`myUri` is a reference to the URI of the crash and the ContentProvider is properly declared on the manifest:

```
   <provider
      android:name=".geo.ContentManager"
      android:authorities="com.myapp.urimanager.data"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false"
      android:multiprocess="true"/>
```

as I said, I can't reproduce that in the office and it does not happen very often, but still, it crashes.

This happens on every Android version (2.3.7, 4.04, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4) and a variety of devices (Sony Xperias, Samsung Galaxy, Moto, Alcatel, LG Optimus, etc).

Anyone have ideas why this is happening ?

I know I can simply `try-catch` the call, but I don't believe that it's the correct approach as it will simply postpone the crash to the next call (this `delete` is a clean-up sequence launched on every app start).

Comment: Did you write the underlying `ContentProvider`? It sounds like the problem may be there.

Comment: yes I did. But it's a very simple matcher against `/location` or `/people` or `\upload`. And the stack trace never gets to it, it crashes inside the Android Framework code `at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:818)`

Comment: What is the value of `myUri` when you call `ContentResolver#delete`?

Comment: as I said, I can't repro, but the Exception message and what I expect it to be matches `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.myapp.urimanager.data/location`